# Loading liferay search container through ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp, search, liferay, containers

I want to reload the data of the search container when the value of the drop down changes.

I have written the AJAX code to call the `serveResource()` method and pass the drop down value, but I'm not sure how to reload or refresh the search container with new data.

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="xxxResourceURL"  id="/A.jsp" escapeXml="false"/>
    A.io.request("<%=xxxResourceURL%>", {
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            data1: vid,
            data2:ltypeid
        },
        on: {
            success: function() {
                alert(this.get('responseData')); //alerts 2
                A.one("#prodDiv").setContent(this.get('responseData'));
            }
        }
    });
```

A.jsp

```
<%
    List prodList=Collections.emptyList();
    try {
        HttpServletRequest httpReq = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(resourceRequest);
        String d1= PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(httpReq).getParameter("data1");
        String d2= PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(httpReq).getParameter("data2");
        System.out.println("JSP-->Vendor Id is**"+d1);
        System.out.println("JSP-->License Type Id is**"+d2);
        DynamicQuery prodQuery=XXXMasterLocalServiceUtil.getProdcuts(Long.parseLong(d1), Long.parseLong(d2));
        prodList=XXXMasterLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(prodQuery);
        out.println("<liferay-ui:search-container headerNames=\"Product Name\">");
        out.println("<liferay-ui:search-container-results results='"+prodList+"' total='"+prodList.size()+"''/>");
        out.println("<liferay-ui:search-container-row className=\"com.liferay.lms.model.ProductMaster\" escapedModel='true' keyProperty=\"productId\" modelVar=\"product\">");
        out.println("<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name=\"Product Name\" property=\"productName\" />");
        out.println("</liferay-ui:search-container-row>");
        out.println("<liferay-ui:search-iterator paginate=\"true\" />");
        out.println("</liferay-ui:search-container>");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception is"+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    %>
```

Please help!

Comment: There are a few different ways to interpret your question, can you post your code/

Comment: This is my requirement.i have a drop down in a liferay portlet and when the user selects a value from the drop down, i want to pass the selected value, get the data from the DB and display in a search container

Comment: Post your ajax call and the relevant html...

Comment: The simplest approach would be to simply serve new HTML that replaces the old search container instead of attempting to replace every line from JSON data.

Comment: I had achieved this using different approach.

Comment: what approach? 

can you post your solution here?